# Reference Request: Neural Networks as Mathematical Models

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, machine-learning, biology, neural-networks

Could you point out some reference books [accessible to an undergrad math student] that deal with the mathematical modelling aspect of neural networks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.ploscompbiol.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pcbi.1001066) is a nice article concerning the mathematical modeling of the neural system of the nematode *C. elegans* (the only species for which the neural system is completely known up to the cellular level). Perhaps you find the article or its references to be interesting.

Hopefully someone else can suggest a reference for a more mathematical approach to modeling neuronal networks - the above article is written from a biological viewpoint.

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps a more computational/physical treatment, but there is still some good mathematics, at least in my opinion, as well.

https://www.scribd.com/doc/311373901/Neural-Networks-and-the-Brain